# Unwrapping an async operation and it's async callback in a TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

I have a method in a service that gets called by my view model to fetch an image. The image is fetched from an external library (iOS API in Xamarin) which uses a callback mechanic instead of being awaitable.

In order to make my method awaitable, I wrap the method in a TaskCompletionSource. The problem though is in the API callback, I need to invoke another method that must return a Task. The completion source sets it's result as a `Task<IBitmap>`, and I then return the CompletionSource Task, which now becomes `Task<Task<IBitmap>>` So what I end up with as my final return value is `Task<Task<IBitmap>>` instead of just `Task<Bitmap>`.

```
public Task<IBitmap> GetAlbumCoverImage(IAlbum album)
{
    var assets = PHAsset.FetchAssetsUsingLocalIdentifiers(new string[] { album.Identifier }, null);

    var asset = assets.FirstOrDefault(item => item is PHAsset);
    if(asset == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Task<IBitmap>>();
    PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageForAsset(
        asset, 
        new CoreGraphics.CGSize(512, 512), 
        PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, 
        null, 
        (image, info) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(this.ConvertUIImageToBitmap(image)));

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}

private Task<IBitmap> ConvertUIImageToBitmap(UIImage image)
{
    var imageData = image.AsJPEG().GetBase64EncodedData(Foundation.NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.SixtyFourCharacterLineLength);
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageData.Count()];

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, imageBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Count()));

    return BitmapLoader.Current.Load(new MemoryStream(imageBytes), 512, 512);
}
```

How should I go about unwrapping the nested Task, so that I'm only returning a `Task<IBitmap>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `TaskCompletionSource<Task<IBitmap>>`, use `TaskCompletionSource<UIImage>` which returns a task that when completed returns an image. Await that task to asynchronously get the result which you can then convert using `ConvertUIImageToBitmap`:

```
public async Task<IBitmap> GetAlbumCoverImage(IAlbum album)
{
    // ...
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<UIImage>(); // create the completion source
    PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageForAsset(
        asset, 
        new CoreGraphics.CGSize(512, 512), 
        PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, 
        null, 
        (image, info) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(image)); // set its result

    UIImage image = await taskCompletionSource.Task; // asynchronously wait for the result
    return await ConvertUIImageToBitmap(image); // convert it
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks. Since the `ConvertUIImageToBitmap` requires a UIImage, I had to change the completion source to  `TaskCompletionSource<UIImage>`. I was then able to pull the UIImage from the awaited task completion result and pass it into the `ConvertUIImageToBitmap` method and await/return the result.

Comment: The `ConvertUIImageToBitmap` does actually need to return a Task. The `BitmapLoader.Current.Load` method returns Task<IBitmap>

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger yeah, I missed the `UIImage` part, but that's the idea.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger that's surprising. You should add the "Async" suffix to task returning methods (i.e. `LoadAsync`).

Comment: In this case, I don't control the API. The Load method is an OSS project (Splat) that provides cross-platform image loading. I'll make an adjustment to my API though to add the async. I had read on MSDN once that unless you have a mix of async/synchronous methods, appending async is just redundant. I guess it's just personal preference